# Cutting and pasting (moving) from Android device over USB with "MTP" now silently leaving the original files instead of moving

Tags: windows-10, usb, android, file-transfer, mtp

With both my Android Phones (Redmi 4A and 6) I've been transferring photos and videos to my Windows 10 machine over USB cable. This apparently uses a protocol called ["MTP"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Media_Transfer_Protocol) and has always worked well enough with at least two phones and two laptops.

But today after moving a number of photos and stopping due to a full drive to move some older ones to an external drive, I went back to moving the remaining files from the phone.

But now, after completing, I find all the original files are still on the phone, so instead of "moving" they have only been "copying".

I've tried to do it using the File Explorer icons and the hotkeys. I've tried ejecting the phone and plugging it in again. I've tried changing the phone from MTP to PTP mode, but then it can't see the files on the phone's SD card. I've tried plugging the USB cable into a different port. I've verified that I'm definitely choosing the scissors icon, and that it's not disabled. I've verified that the progress indicator says "Moving" and not "Copying".

I see no error or warning messages on either the laptop or the phone.

Since it uses MTP I don't think I can move the files by the commandline, but maybe there's a way.

Is this a known issue? Googling I found nothing similar at all. Could there be some kind of hidden read-only mode I can disable? Is there a log file where I might find some diagnostic? Is there another tool to move files via MTP, or a way other than MTP.

I know I can shut down my phone, put its SD card into my laptop and just move the files between drives. But that's a fiddly process. It's also a workaround and I'd like to get to the bottom of the problem, which might be useful on Superuser for future people in the same situation when they Google it.

Comment: Does anybody have any advice to offer on what's wrong with this question that it should be closed?

Comment: If you are talking about the media database / files out-of-sync mess in Android (that's why it would be off-topic), usually you can go to apps in settings, show system apps and find an app called `Media Storage`, force stop it, clear its data, reboot and don't panic (it would look like that all media files are gone, for some time) and wait (so better do it before you sleep or something), then they would be in sync again. Not guarantee to be "safe" (well, it could hardly cause actual file lost, if not never) and work on every device (e.g. in case a reboot doesn't spawn it and trigger a rescan).

Comment: @TomYan: Hmm I've never heard of this media database / files out-of-sync mess before. But I am pretty new to Android I suppose. Thanks for the tips! ... Well I couldn't find the appropriate setting or app on my Xiaomi/Redmi, but your tip made me think rebooting the phone might also work... and it did! So thank you very much.

Comment: Frankly, I would avoid MTP. You can download simple FTP server/client applications for Android (ditto for PC). There is a slight drawback in that thumbnails from your e.g. gallery app will have to be manually deleted from your phone (since they may appear but will point to nothing) but most of the time, these orphaned thumbnails can be selected in one go.